# Django dbbackup - Postgresql .psql.bin file format?

Tags: django, postgresql, backup

I have been installing and using **django-dbbackup** extension today (https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbbackup).

I use the S3 Storage option.

When i run a 'dbbackup', i obtain a file in format 'filename-2022-08-26-171845.psql.bin'.

Is there a way to uncompress/read inside this **'.psql.bin'** file format ?

I would like to access the query that have been backup, like i would do with a '.sql' file.

Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer.

There is two connectors existing for PostgreSQL in django-dbbackup :

- dbbackup.db.postgresql. PgDumpBinaryConnector (by default)
- dbbackup.db.postgresql.PgDumpConnector

If you want to use the non-binary, you need to specify connector mapping in your settings :

```
> DBBACKUP_CONNECTOR_MAPPING = {  
> 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':'dbbackup.db.postgresql.PgDumpConnector',
> }
```